# Display categories list in Wordpress without subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, categories

I am attempting to show categories in a list, but without displaying subcatgories. My current code is:

```html
<?php if (is_category()) {
  $this_category = get_category($cat);
  if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "") {
    echo "<ul>";
    wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=
&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID);
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}?>
```

Which displays the categories nicely

[image]

but when I added a sub-category it looked like this:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you want to get as a final results. You said you want to list categories, and not do show their children, and given first sample by you seems does what you want. Then at last part you again say that "when i added sub-category". Why you added subcategory if you don't want to show subs?

Comment: Yes, I want the list to only display the "parent" categories.

Comment: I added it because I need the function of it, but I don't want it displayed in the actual list.

Answer (score 0):

Use get_categories() instead.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/#Get_only_top_level_categories

It has "parent" parameter which you can set to 0 and get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a css problem to me : you probably want to hide the subcategory item until it's clicked or hovered